# Import a variable from Flask to a webpage without reloading it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, flask

I would like to import the variable **test_data** from Flask to my webpage, without reloading it. Just clicking a button. But I couldn't succeed so far. Any ideas?

## Flask:

```
@blueprint.route('/data_analysis')
@login_required
def data_analysis():
    test_data = 'getting data from here' ### THIS VARIABLE
return render_template('index.html', test_data= test_data)
```

## Javascript:

```
$("#load_data_btn").click(function(){

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', '/home/data_analysis', true);

    request.onload = function() {
    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
        var test_data = {{ test_data }};
        alert(test_data);
        // Success!
        var resp = this.response;
    } else {
    // We reached our target server, but it returned an error
    }};
    request.onerror = function() {
    // There was a connection error of some sort
    };
    request.send();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're confusing Jinja which renders the html and javascript file before sending it to the client, and the server side stuff. What you're doing is creating an html file that will have something like:

```
<script>
. . .
var test_data = "getting data from here"; # hard coded when user visits site 
alert(test_data);                         # rather than dynamically retrieved
. . .
</script>
```

But you're code probably isn't getting here because you're route isn't actually returning anything.

If you **don't** want to reload the page you should return the variable encoded as JSON rather than render the template:

```
from flask import jsonify 

@blueprint.route('/data_analysis')
@login_required
def data_analysis():
    return jsonify({"value": "getting data from here"}) 

$("#load_data_btn").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("/home/data_analysis", function(response){
        alert(response["value"]);
    });
});
```

Comment: I have been studying Python and Flask and I have a little knowledge in Javascript. Your answer was clear and solved the problem. Thank you.